# how to take out the mean from python matrix

Tags: python, matrix, row

I am currently working on this project,

```
 import numpy as np

 COLUMN_NUM = 4
 datos = np.genfromtxt('a.csv', delimiter=',')[1:]

 #data = np.pad(data, (0, COLUMN_NUM - len(data) % COLUMN_NUM), 'constant')
 ds= datos.reshape((-1, COLUMN_NUM))

 print ds
```

I am gettings this results:

```
[[  4.    33.29  33.23  33.23]
 [ 33.29  33.23  33.29  33.29]
 [ 33.29  33.33  33.29  33.33]
 [ 33.29  33.33  33.33  33.37]
 [ 33.33  33.33  33.33  33.33]
 [ 33.37  33.37  33.37  33.37]]
```

I been trying to take out the mean from each ROW indiviadually but am having a lot of trouble. Can any lease help on figuring this out? Thank you. I am really a new at python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ndarry.mean` and pass it `axis=1`:

```
>>> datos.mean(axis=1)
[ 2.  5.  8.]
```

`axis=1` will tell `mean` you want the mean of each row.
The other options are to not pass anything (then `mean` will return the mean of the whole "matrix") and `axis=0` which will return the mean of every column.

Refer to [`ndarray.mean`'s docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html).

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting this:     items *= arr.shape[ax]
IndexError: tuple index out of range Do you have any idea why? I aonly did: print datos.mean(axis=1)

Answer (score -1):

To take the mean of each row of a matrix use the following code

```
l = []
for i in mat:
    sum = 0
    for j in i:
        sum = sum + j
    l.append(sum/len(i))
print(l)
```

Comment: So throwing away vectorization completely?

Comment: Thank you however I am gettin an error: 
    for i in mat:
NameError: name 'mat' is not defined can you help me?

Comment: @CristianJEstrada replace mat with the name of whatever matrix you want the mean of.